# JavaScript: XMLSerializer object detection IE8 & modern browsers

Tags: javascript, serialization

I'm trying to do object detection to prevent IE8 from throwing errors in the absence of `new XMLSerializer()` however I have been unsuccessful in finding a cross-browser way to approach the issue. I typically use `object!='undefined'` however I haven't found a cross-browser way of implementing this.

Here are some of the ways I've tested in Firefox 10 and IE8...

```
if (typeof new XMLSerializer!='undefined') {alert('unsupported, 1');}

if (typeof new XMLSerializer()!='undefined') {alert('unsupported, 2');}

if (new XMLSerializer!='undefined') {alert('unsupported, 3');}

if (XMLSerializer!='undefined') {alert('unsupported, 4');}

if (window.XMLSerializer!='undefined') {alert('unsupported, 5');}

if (typeof XMLSerializer !== 'undefined') {alert('unsupported, 6');}
```

So how can we implement object detection for the `XMLSerializer` without triggering errors in unsupported browsers such as IE8?

Comment: most feature detection is usually done by `typeof XMLSerializer !== 'undefined'`  I'm not positive if this will work in this case though without testing.

Comment: Did that obviously and it didn't work hence my question.

Comment: Your question did not indicate, which is why I posted as a comment :)  Could you please describe "didn't work"?

Comment: Also if worst comes to worst and the typical feature detection of `if (window.XMLSerializer)` and the one I mentioned above, you can always wrap it in a `try { } catch { }`

Comment: Updated...meh...yeah but I feel using try/catch is laming out like having to use setTimeout because the DOM has no method to fire an event to the last phase. >__>

Comment: Your question still does not list the one I posted.

Comment: There, added it. Firefox isn't liking any of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be testing if it has it by this:

```
if (typeof window.XMLSerializer !== 'undefined') {
    alert('Has XMLSerializer');
} else {
    alert('No has XMLSerializer');
}
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/fGZbL/1/

Or the original fiddle I posted should work too (this tests truthiness of `window.XMLSerializer`): http://jsfiddle.net/fGZbL/